# fetch text and image both in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I want to fetch text or image in modal. I can fetch text by textCont. In a div may have text or image. So which one will have there, it will fetch it.

Here is my code for text.

```
var contId = 0;
var contBodyElement = null;

$('.body').find('.edit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    contBodyElement = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    var contBody = contBodyElement.textContent;
    contId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset["contid"];
    //console.log(contBody);
    $('#my-editor').val(contBody);
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

HTML

```html
<div class="header">
  <div data-contid={{ $templates->id }}>
    <img src="{{ URL::to($templates->header) }}" alt="" />
    <div class="dropdown-content"> 
      <a href="#" class="edit">Edit content</a>  <a href="#">Edit Background</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="cont-one" data-contid={{ 2 }}>
  <h2><p>{{ $body->cont_one }}</p></h2> 
  <div class="dropdown-content"> 
    <a href="#" class="edit">Edit content</a>  <a href="#">Edit Background</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the snippet editor [<>] to add the code and RENDERED html so the code can be tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be great if you share html code from which you wanted to fetch texts and image.

For image you can get image src attribute like this

```
var src_image_attr = $('img').attr('src');
```

and to set it to img element-:

```
$("#my_image").attr("src", src_image_attr);
```

Comment: Please UPDATE your question with the HTML instead of posting it in a comment